# A weaker version of the ABC conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture, music-theory

I posted this question over at Stackexchange, where a user informed me that it was probably more appropriate for Mathoverflow.  Here's to hoping that the answer is out there:

The ABC conjecture states that there are a finite number of integer triples (a,b,c) such that $\frac {\log \left( c \right)}{\log \left( \text{rad} \left( abc \right) \right)}>1+\varepsilon $, where $a+b=c$ and $\varepsilon > 0$.

I am however more interested in a weaker version of the ABC conjecture where the following inequality holds true: $\frac {\log \left( c \right)}{\log \left( a \: \text{rad} \left( bc \right) \right)}>1+\varepsilon $.  This weaker conjecture has a number of applications in music theory — specifically concerning temperament theory.  For instance, it establishes a type of intuitive complexity metric on various temperaments, and then lets us bound a finite number of these temperaments underneath a given complexity. (if you are not familiar with temperament theory, you can think of these "temperaments" as z-module homomorphisms from one free abelian group to another of lower rank)

It is easy to see that this conjecture is implied by the ABC conjecture.  However, I was wondering if this weaker version is already proven?  And if not, what is the best approach to a proof that does not rely on ABC?  I'm not very familiar with number theory so I don't know where to start.

Comment: Can you post a link to the stackexchange question and vice versa too?

Comment: Here is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234697/a-weaker-version-of-the-abc-conjecture

Comment: For future reference, this is a music theory question with a good fit for MO. Thanks for pointing out the musical reason for asking about this weaker conjecture, it makes a potentially borderline question very interesting.

Comment: @David, what would make this question "potentially borderline"
without the music-theory motivation?

Comment: If anyone is interested in the music theory aspect of this, that is discussed here: http://xenharmonic.wikispaces.com/ABC%2C+High+Quality+Commas%2C+and+Epimericity

Comment: Given the state of interest in ABC among non-specialists, if someone asked 'what if I do x to the statement of the ABC conjecture?', then it would be (for me) merely a curiosity. I suppose 'borderline' was a bit strong, but perhaps I'm just on the watch out for repeats of what happened with recent ABC-related questions.

Comment: @Joël (and up-voters of the comment): I am completely with David Roberts without (the) motivation to me this question would definitely be at least borderline. Of course the motivation could be something other then music-theory it could be also inner mathematical and would not even have to be an application in any sense. But *only* "what is known on this or that modification of well-known problem" would not be a good MO question, and even less so if it is a very well-known problem currently 'in the news'.     

Answer (score 17):

According to [Rockytheflyingsquirrel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234697/a-weaker-version-of-the-abc-conjecture), this is still an open problem.  I made this answer community wiki so as not to benefit from a squirrel's hard work.

Answer (score 10):

Just to point out there are infinitely many coprime solutions to
$\frac {\log \left( c \right)}{\log \left( a \: \text{rad} \left( bc \right) \right)} > 1$

Take $a=1$ and $b,c$ [consecutive powerful numbers](https://oeis.org/A060355).

If $n,n+1$ are consecutive powerful numbers so are $4n(n+1),4n(n+1)+1$ so the solutions without epsilon are infinite.

Comment: The fact that you keep multiplying by 4 seems promising.  Are you sure that sequence tends to 1?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.12

Comment: In fact this sequence deserves more attention.  Can one prove that  from the sequence (n,n+1) one has infinitely many prime members of (2n+1)?  We may have the opportunity of putting two conjectures head-to-head.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.12 

Comment: @Gerhard it is interesting how relatively big the 3-full part of n(n+1) can be. If it is sufficiently big it will disprove both this and the abc conjecture.

Comment: Re: "tends to 1". I suppose in general it tends to 1. Repeatedly multiplying by 4 is exponential in 2. Unfortunately squaring $2n+1$ gives doubly exponential growth. Doubt the product of the smaller $n$ can compensate the doubly exponential growth. Well might be wrong.